# How to resolve Bootstrap and Clarity styling conflicts when using forms

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, vmware-clarity

I'm using Clarity and Bootstrap together in an Angular project, but styling conflicts seem to be popping up, as the styling is not working as intended.

I've tried changing the CSS around in Chrome devtools. I noticed that `reboot.scss` might be causing some of the problems, but I don't know what to do about that if it is.

Here's the component code.

```
<h3>New Post</h3>
<form #productEditorForm="ngForm" clrForm>
  <clr-select-container>
    <label>Location</label>
    <select clrSelect name="Location" [(ngModel)]="LocationID">
      <option *ngFor="let location of Locations" [value]="location.ID">{{ location.Name }}</option>
    </select>
  </clr-select-container>
  <clr-input-container>
    <label>Images</label>
    <input clrInput #files type="file"/>
  </clr-input-container>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

The expected appearance of the selectbox is like the examples [found here](https://clarity.design/documentation/select#top). The expected appearance for the button is like the primary button [found here](https://clarity.design/documentation/buttons#examples); the font size of the buttons is supposed to be .5rem, but the actual size is 1. The intended default font is Metropolis, but the actual font is Segoe UI. The page isn't supposed to have flickering scrollbars and jittery contents, but the actual page does. Where do I go from here?

Comment: What is the reason you want to use Bootstrap? Clarity is meant to be full featured, so Bootstrap is not required and typically not necessary.

Comment: I'm using its carousel feature to display posts to users.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Angular carousel implementations (this one is built upon Bootstrap but is able to be used in an isolated way https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and they would be able to provide the necessary functionality.

If you do load Bootstrap, you would want to load it before Clarity so Clarity has the final say on the styling.